# Geometric meaning of localization at $(1+I)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, intuition, localization

Let $I\vartriangleleft A$ be an ideal of a commutative ring. Consider the submonoid $1+I\subset A$. What is the geometric interpretation of localization at this submonoid? How does it relate to the quotient $A/I$?

Comment: Have you tried some examples? For instance, if you take $(x_1,\cdots,x_m)\subset k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$, what do you get?

Comment: This is called the Zariski localization (see [the MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/351306)) of $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ along $V(I)$. You can see that this is equivalent to the colimit of $A_f$ where the basic open $D(f)$ contains $V(I)$, so it is somehow the "germs along $V(I)$".

Comment: As for the relation between $A/I$ and $(1 + I)^{-1}A$, maybe thinking about pure ideals will help? The two rings are canonically isomorphic iff $I$ is pure.

Comment: Dear @KReiser, what do I get? I only see the localization sits inside the ring of formal power series. What is the intuition?

Comment: @Yai0Phah, do you see a concrete description of the localization of $k[x_1,\dots ,x_n]$ at $1+ \langle x_1,\dots ,x_n \rangle$?

Comment: You should be able to show the following. Let $A$ be a ring and $I\subseteq A$ an ideal. First, there is a canonical map $(1+I)^{-1}A\to A/I$. Next, any preimage of an invertible element in $A/I$ is invertible in $(1+I)^{-1}A$. In particular, when $I$ is an maximal ideal, you should be able to prove that $(1+I)^{-1}A$ coincides with the usual localization at the maximal ideal $I$.

Comment: @hm2020 I'm not sure what you're getting at... If a prime ideal is pure then it's necessarily a minimal prime. So in your example $\mathfrak{m} = 0$ and everything is as it should be. The claim I made is also very much true, see e.g. [stacks Lemma 04PS]

Comment: @BadamBaplan: There is a "canonical" map $\phi: (1+I)^{-1}A \rightarrow A/I$ defined by $\phi(a/(1+x)):=a/(1+\overline{x}) \cong a/1=a$. Is this the "canonical" map you are speaking of? You must map any element $1+x$ to a unit in $A/I$.

Comment: @BadamBaplan - what do you mean by "pure ideal"?

Comment: @hm2020 An ideal $I$ is pure when $A/I$ is a flat $A$-module

Comment: @hm2020 yes that is the canonical map. I think we're on the same page, it's just a matter of terminology. My comment wasn't deep, I just wanted to point out the case where $A/I$ and $(1+I)^{-1}$ coincide, which turns out to be quite geometric

Comment: Crossposted: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/404716

Answer (score 1):

**Question:** "What is the geometric interpretation of localization at this submonoid?"

**Answer:** If $k$ is any field and $\mathfrak{m}:=(x_1-a_1,..,x_n-a_n)\subseteq A:=k[x_1,..,x_n]$ the following holds: for any polynomial $g(x_1,..,x_n)$
it follows

$$g(x_1,..,x_n)=g(a_1+(x_1-a_1),..,a_n+(x_n-a_n))=g(a_1,..,a_n)+ y$$

with $y\in \mathfrak{m}$. If $S:=1+\mathfrak{m} \subseteq A-\mathfrak{m}$ it follows there is a canonical injective map

$$S^{-1}A \rightarrow A_{\mathfrak{m}}.$$

And any element $f(x)/g(x)\in A_{\mathfrak{m}}$ has $g(a_1,..,a_n):=a \neq 0$. Hence

$$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{f(x)}{a+y}= \frac{\frac{1}{a}f}{1+z}$$

with $z\in \mathfrak{m}$. Hence the canonical map $S^{-1}A \rightarrow A_{\mathfrak{m}}$ is an isomorphism. A similar argument holds for any algebraically closed field $k$ and $A$ any finitely generated $k$-algebra that is an integral domain.

You may wonder what happens if $I:=\mathfrak{m}_1^{l_1}\cdots \mathfrak{m}_d^{l_d}$ and you consider $(1+I)^{-1}A$. If you consider $I:=\mathfrak{m}^l$, I suspect the localization $S^{-1}A$ is related to "taking partial derivatives" at $\mathfrak{m}$ (vaguely). if $S_l:=(1+\mathfrak{m}^l)$ you get a sequence of subsets

$$ S_l \subseteq S_{l-1} \subseteq \dots \subseteq S_1$$

with canonical maps

$$S_l^{-1}A \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow S_1^{-1}A  \cong A_{\mathfrak{m}}.$$

**Note:** If $A$ is a domain it follows for any maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$, that $ (1+\mathfrak{m})^{-1}A \rightarrow A_{\mathfrak{m}} \subseteq K(A)$ are subrings of the quotient field $K(A)$. The quotient $A/\mathfrak{m}$ is not contained in the quotient field in general.

Comment: Dear @hm2020, I would *very* much like to read more about your "partial derivative" intuition. Please elaborate!

Comment: @Arrow - for any maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m} \subseteq k[x_1,..,x_n]$ corresponding to a $k$-rational point $p$ of $\mathbb{A}^n_k$, it follows the truncation $A:=k[x_i]/\mathfrak{m}^{l+1}$ may be viewed as the "ring of Taylor polynomials evaluated at the point $p$". When you Zariski localize at $1+\mathfrak{m}^{l+1}$ it seems (vaguely) you "do something similar". You may take the direct limit $lim_l S_l^{-1}A$ of the sequence above and this "seems" to be some type of "ring of Taylor polynomials".